# Iframe is blank on Android 5 and 6

Tags: android, cordova, iframe, android-permissions

I hava en android app made using cordova. The app uses an Iframe which works well from android 7. But for Android 5 and 6 is not working, it only shows a white screen. Even if I try to show another website it is still blank. The only way to have some content inside is by embedding a video.

Do you have any hint about this issue? Currently I'm not getting any error just the white screen.

Comment: to debug white page under Android 5/6, create 2 simulators with theses versions. then run the app, open chrome/debugger and target your simulator, you ll see the error in the console

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I already did it, but the console is not throwing any message, neither with youtube nor with any other website. It's just the white screen

Comment: weird, maybe because it crash before, and nothing in logs inside android studio (filtered by app name) ? can you put your code on git ? to  test it

Comment: Due to business reasons I can't put the URL that I'am trying to access. But apparently is a mixed content issue. Not sure why the issue is ignored from android 7 and above..

Comment: that make sense, old android's are more permissive